# Laravel: method does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, nomethoderror

i have a problem with Laravel, becouse it is not finding my route:
Look the error:

```
(1/1) BadMethodCallException
Method [sendEmail] does not exist.
```

My route "web.php":

```
Route::get('/', function () {
  return view('index');
});

Route::get('/studio', 'StudioController@index');
Route::get('/studio/contratos', 'StudioController@contract');
Route::get('/studio/agenda', 'StudioController@agenda');
Route::get('/studio/clientes', 'StudioController@client');
Route::get('/studio/ensaios', 'StudioController@assay');

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/email/{id}', 'UserController@sendEmail');
```

My controller "UserController.php":

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Mail;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function sendEmail(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);

        Mail::send('emails.reminder', ['user' => $user], function ($m) use ($user) {
            $m->from('aaaaaag@hotmail.com', 'a Your Application');

            $m->to($user->email, $user->name)->subject('Your Reminder!');
        });
    }
}
```

A stranger things is, it works in local server, but when I upload it in live server, I have this error ://

Thanks guys

---

The error Image:

[Image error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uxUc.jpg)

Comment: Can you show us the code from where you are accessing this route?

Comment: Im accessing from the URL -> `www.photobooker.com.br/email/1`

I have a user with ID 1

Comment: It seems okay. Are you sure you have pushed the code on live environment?

Comment: Yeah, now I do a `php artisan down`, then `php artisan up`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Mail;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function sendEmail($id)
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);

        Mail::send('emails.reminder', ['user' => $user], function ($m) use ($user) {
            $m->from('aaaaaag@hotmail.com', 'a Your Application');

            $m->to($user->email, $user->name)->subject('Your Reminder!');
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Resolved, i run this command:

```
rm -rf vendor/laravel
```

and then:

```
composer update
```

I think is a type of bug :///

Thanks guys